# preg_replace to replace extra symbols

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace

My problem has to do with removing extra code from a return array.

The array currently has this `/\b` around the name then `\b/` follows after.
There are too many to go through by hand, so I'm looking into `preg_replace` to take out the extras.

I'm just not sure if it is the easiest way.

Example:

```
'/\bAngelena\b/','/\bAngeles\b/','/\bAngelia\b/','/\bAngelic\b/','/\bAngelica\b/','/\bAngelika\b/','/\bAngelina\b/','/\bAngeline\b/','/\bAngelique\b/','/\bAngelita\b/','/\bAngella\b/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $array[$k] = preg_replace ("#/\\b|\\b/#", "", $v);
}
```

will do what you're asking for. :)